# How do I avoid HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_16 for text based logos in an email?

Tags: html-email, spam-prevention

I'm trying to create an email template with the logo at the top however the logo is entirely text based, with a custom layout and font. Something like this: http://3cd.co/image/3M2V2X2q1T0n

It's getting 1 point in SpamAssassin due to the rule HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_16. From what I understand, this rule is designed to prevent the display of text in an image to avoid certain rules in spam filters. Is there a way to avoid this to prevent these emails from going directly to spam? I'd like to display the branding in their font and style, and it seems the only alternative I can figure out is just by using plain text for the company name. Any suggestions on avoiding this rule?

Answer (score 4):

The only way to get around it is to add more text *words* to your emails until you have more than 1600 bytes of words. How to calculate: copy/paste your entire email into something like notepad that will drop all the formatting, html tags (if you're using an html emailer), images, etc and just give you the body of the email. Save the file, check out it's size and make sure it's larger than 1600 bytes.

BTW, you may want to go ahead and have more than 3200 bytes of text while you're at it, or you'll just hit the next rules on your way up (2000, 2400, 2800, 3200). Depending on your config those rules may penalize your email less, but why not go ahead and kill it while you're at it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to copy and paste legal texts, privacy notices, etc. into your signature footer, to increase the percentage of text versus images.
Still one drawback, and that is that when replying or forwarding the email, it becomes uncomfortably large. And more if the same email is exchanged several times.